# cap deploy: could not find capistrano

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capistrano

Capistrano was bulletproof when I last used it.
However, it's been a few weeks since I last used it and I'm now getting errors like this:

```
cap deploy 
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'capistrano' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making sure it exists

```
gem list
```

It could be you emptied the gemset or this is a new gemset (I see you're using RVM).

You may also have had it in the bundle

```
bundle list
```

and just need to put it (back?) in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes rvm doesn't work correctly. You can try setting it to default

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195 --default
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Capistrano is installed by running the list command

`gem list`

If you do not see it in the list, you may simply install it

`gem install capistrano`